# unexpected T_VARIABLE error whilst setting up form validation

Tags: php

i am trying to set up form validation but keep receiving **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE on line 146** whenever i try to load the page.

lines 133-153 of my code are

```
<?php
    if (array_key_exists('submit',$_POST)){
    //set up layout
    echo '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="height: 140px;">
          <tr>
            <td width="60%" valign="middle"><a href="index.php"><img src="resources/img/kite.png" alt="" width="250" height="101" border="0"/></a></td>
            <td width="40%" align="left" valign="middle"></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </form></td>
          </tr>
        </table>';
         // Fields that are on form
        $expected = array('name', 'email', 'comments');
        // Set required fields
        $required = array('name', 'comments');
        // Initialize array for errors
        $errors = array();
    exit;
    }
    ?>
```

many thanks in advance!

Comment: I fail to see any issues in this snippet (so does my IDE) - are you sure the source of the error is not in lines prior to 133?  Could you post a larger code sample?

Comment: What file does the error message specify? Is it the same file as the one in your post?

Comment: there is no php code prior to line 133 and the error message is for ie6.php - the file in which the code is found. dreamweaver has reported a syntax error on all three lines containing arrays.

Comment: remove the white space between the array values you might have some special characters in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this kind of error sometimes when i copy and paste code from an outside source (websource , or microsoft word). Depending on the editor you use, try to see if you have any option to display invisible characters, such as spaces, tabs, and new lines.

You probably have a foreign character that is not visible.

If you don't have such an editor, simply erase the white space in the line causing the problem and add your own white space using a the space bar or tab.

try that and let us know.